# Rectification transformation with cv.fisheye.initUndistortRectifyMap

Tags: opencv, image-processing, homography, fisheye

Starting point is [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnBZ2.png), which I want to undistort and transform images into bird's eye view in one single call of `cv.remap`. That for, I'm using `numpy==1.15.0` and `opencv-python==3.4.2.17` in a `Python 3.7` Jupyter notebook.

First, I determine the intrinsic camera parameters and distortion coefficients calling

```
rms, K, D, _, _ = cv.fisheye.calibrate(obj_p, img_p, shape[::-1], None, None,
    flags=(cv.fisheye.CALIB_RECOMPUTE_EXTRINSIC + cv.fisheye.CALIB_CHECK_COND + 
           cv.fisheye.CALIB_FIX_SKEW),
    criteria=(cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 1e-6))
```

where `shape` is the shape of the [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnBZ2.png). Afterwards I call

```
K_new = cv.fisheye.estimateNewCameraMatrixForUndistortRectify(
    K, D, shape[::-1], np.eye(3))
```

to adjust the camera matrix to the undistorted image. Calling `cv.remap` using maps generated from those values by calling

```
map_x, map_y = cv.fisheye.initUndistortRectifyMap(
    K, D, np.eye(3), K_new, shape[::-1], cv.CV_16SC2)
```

results in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v50Mc.png).

Secondly, I use the undistorted image to find four points in the image which I can use in `cv.getPerspectiveTransform` to get `H` for transformation into bird's eye view. Using `H` in `cv.warpPerspective` on the already undistorted image results in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk7yo.png).

Lastly, I want to combine both so I only need to call `cv.remap` once on the [first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnBZ2.png) to get to the [last image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk7yo.png). Trying to do so calling

```
R = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(K), H)
R = np.dot(R, K)

K_new = cv.fisheye.estimateNewCameraMatrixForUndistortRectify(
    K, D, bird_shape, R)

map_x, map_y = cv.fisheye.initUndistortRectifyMap(
    K, D, R, K_new, (bird_shape[0]*15, bird_shape[1]*15) , cv.CV_16SC2)
```

and using the resulting maps in `cv.remap` on the [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnBZ2.png) resulted in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMWVT.png) (increased the resulting image size because the resulting image in `bird_shape` is almost entirely black).

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance! I can also make the whole notebook available, if necessary.